# Coin vibration motor terminal question

Tags: vibration-motor

I am using a 3V coin vibration motor and using a 3V coin battery. Red wire of the motor connects to 3V and the black/blue wire connects to GND. What happens if the terminals are connected incorrectly and the black/blue wire is connected to 3V? Will the motor not turn at all? Or will it turn and burn out?

Looking at the [datasheet](https://www.google.co.nz/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDUQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.precisionmicrodrives.com%2Forder-parts%2Fproduct%2F308-100-8mm-vibration-motor-3-4mm-type&ei=hRapU7q_EYimkwXT34HQBg&usg=AFQjCNGEb3HpmS0QLpZk5H4j7fPEDo25lw&sig2=hZlwju055IB5BJQT--lIRA), the motor has 6 poles. Does that mean the motor can turn in one direction only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience small vibration motors can turn in both directions, but with some preference for the direction indicated in the datasheet.

Comment: @David: Thanks for accepting, but note that it is advised to wait some time (at least a few hours, preferably a day) before accepting an answer, to give people (in all time zones) a chance to react.